# Automatic Semantic Clustering and Tagging of sentences using NLP

Tags: python, nlp, clustering, word2vec

## NLP Analysis for keyword clustering

I have a set of keywords for search engines and I would like to create a python script to classify and tag them under unknown categories.

To make it clear I should have an output like this one, without knowing the categories (Product, Colour, Accessory, Brand...):
+----------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------+
|.......Keywords............|.Product...|.Colour.|.Accessory.|.Brand...|
+----------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------+
|.red shoes with heels.|.shoes......|.red......|.heels.........|..............|
|.Apple computer.........|.computer.|............|..................|.Apple....|
|.Armani blue shoes....|.shoes......|.blue.....|..................|.Armani..|
|.black mouse..............|.mouse.....|.black...|..................|..............|
|.gaming laptop...........|.computer.|.............|..................|..............|
+----------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------+

Any suggestions on how I could be able to do it?

I am currently using Word2Vec to find similarities between words and some APIs to recognize Brands and entities in the keywords

```
    model2 = models.Word2Vec.load('semantic_clustering/datasets/it/it.bin')
    with open('tmp/kw_msm.txt') as f:
        kwlist = f.readlines()
    kwlist = [x.strip() for x in kwlist

    # unique_words = list(set([word for word in kw.split(' ') for kw in kwlist]))
    freq_words = defaultdict(int)
    words = set()
    for kw in kwlist:
        for word in kw.split(' '):
            freq_words[word] += 1
            words.add(word)
    sorted_freq_words = sorted(freq_words.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    # Creating Dataframe with words as columns
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=words)
    df['keyword'] = kwlist
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        for w in row['keyword'].split():
            df.loc[i, w] = 1

    good_words = [w for w in words if kw_in_vocab(w, model2)]

    KW_MODEL = model2[good_words]
    NUM_CLUSTERS = 10
    kclusterer = KMeansClusterer(NUM_CLUSTERS, distance=nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance, repeats=25)
    assigned_clusters = kclusterer.cluster(KW_MODEL, assign_clusters=True)
    clusters = {}
    for i, w in enumerate(good_words):
        clusters[w] = assigned_clusters[i]
    sorted_clusters = sorted(clusters.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    for k in sorted_clusters:
        print(k)
```

This is a snippet of code I am using, creating a sparse matrix of words and clustering the columns with a fixed number of clusters, it's only a first test